# How did « comme » + « bien » compound to signify « combien » (quelle quantité, quel nombre)?

Tags: étymologie

How do *comme* and *bien* semantically appertain to [*comme*'s definitions](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/combien) below in 2021 Modern French? Neither of them signifies the definitions below.

> 1. Dans quelle mesure, à quel point.
> 2. quelle quantité, quel nombre.

[combien | Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/combien)

> 11e s. (in NPR); de l'ancien français com « comme » et [bien](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/bien_1).

[COMBIEN : Etymologie de COMBIEN](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/combien)

> Composé de l'a. fr. *com (comme***)* et de *bien**.

Comment: You understand  if you look at the etymology of *comme*, it takes a better knowledge of Latin than mine to explain it clearly. Latin SE might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

The French ***combien*** is unique among the Romance languages.

All of them inherited a word from the Latin *[**quantus**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quantus)* ("how much/how many/how big"). It is *quant* in French, Catalan and Occitan, *quanto* in Italian and Portuguese, *cuanto* in Spanish, *cât* in Romanian, and so on.

However, the French *quant* was competing with its homonymous *quant*<sup>1</sup>, inherited from the Latin *[**quando**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quando)* ("when"). The reason is that unlike the remaining Romance languages, French turned the Latin last consonant *D* into a *T* to match the way it was pronounced. Spanish distinguish *cuando* from *cuanto*, Italian *quando* from *quanto*, Romanian *cât* from *când*, and so on but there was a clash in French.

Because of this collision, French had to find an alternative. It replaced<sup>2</sup> the first *quant* by the periphrasis ***com bien*** (i.e. *comme bien* / *comment bien*) that eventually merged into the new adverb ***combien***. Here *comme* comes from the late Latin *[quomodo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quomodo)* (literally: "what way", i.e. "how") and *bien* from the Latin *bene* ("well") so *combien* literally means "how well".

Some linguists think that this creation might have been influenced by a Germanic adstrate, because of a similar construction in it: German has *wie viel* ("how many") and Dutch *hoeveel* ("how many/how much").

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Later, ***quant*** was modified to ***quand*** to show its Latin roots but without affecting its pronunciation. We still pronounce ***T*** in *Quan**d** elle viendra*: /kɑ̃**t**ɛlvjɛ̃dʁa/.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>This ***quant*** only survives in the idiom *[quant à](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quant%20%C3%A0)*.</sub>

Comment: Très intéressant. Sur le fait que l'on prononce T en faisant la liaison à la fin de quand, n'est-ce pas plutôt la façon habituelle de transformer des son lors des liaisons (s->z, d->t, g->k) plutôt qu'un vestige étymologique du latin ?

Comment: @XouDo Ce qui est un vestige étymologique du Latin, c'est le *D* final du masculin qui a été restauré par Vaugelas. Ce *D* se prononçait et s'écrivait *T* en ancien français.  On retrouve la même chose avec *gran**d*** qui s'est d'abord aussi écrit avec un *T* final plus conforme avec la phonétique. Tous les *D* placés en position finale se prononçaient *T* au moyen âge, *pren**d**-il* s'écrivait *pren**t** il* (*ainsi qu'il est yci figuré, et la se **prent il** par le pié.*)